# Inverse discrete Fourier transform of across specified dimension in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft, ifft

In Matlab, `ifft(X,[],2)` ([link to documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html)) computes the inverse discrete Fourier transform of X across the dimension 2.

Is there a way to accomplish this with `numpy.fft.ifft` ([link to documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html#numpy.fft.ifft))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want

```
np.fft.ifft(x, axis=1)
```

In numpy, dimensions are commonly referred to as "axes", and the second dimension is axis 1 (since Python indexing starts at 0 rather than 1).

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I couldn't figure out what the docs meant by axis.